# ASIHttprequest get progress for chunked transfer encoding?

Tags: iphone, http, chunked-encoding

The `ASIProgressDelegate` `setProgress` method always get 1 when downlonding chunked encoding? 
How to get the progress of downlonding chunked encoding?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chunked-encoding, sometimes, you will not know the content-length before hand, so you won't be able to know the overall progress. The most you can know is the number of bytes received so far.

Comment: Thank you!but, at first ,the server tell the length of the file , how can i get the downloaded bytes?  the ASIPorgressDelegate always callback when the file had been downloaded.

Comment: @see: There is `didReceiveBytes` method in the delegate that you can implement to record the number of bytes received so far. It probably is a missing feature in the implementation if the progress is not available when the content-length is explicitly set in the header - but I am not sure since I haven't looked at everything in the source code.

Comment: request:didReceiveBytes also callback one time when file downloaded finish